# Where can I find a more or less complete list of XML tags that Skype supports?

Tags: xml, documentation, skype

On [this official Skype documentation page](http://developer.skype.com/skypekit/reference/dotnet/html/class_skype_kit_1_1_skt_message.html#details) it says:

> Skype for Windows supports displaying many XML tags, but only a
>   sub-set is regularly used and should be supported by the UI for a good
>   experience.

I haven't been able to find a resource describing the "many XML tags".

**Is there such a page, and where can I find it?**

Comment: Have you tried posted a request for the information on the Skype Developer Forums (http://devforum.skype.com/)?

Comment: No, I was thinking that SO is the place to be for all my development needs. I guess I should follow your advice. Thanks!

Comment: I know what you mean! Please post back here if you get an answer.

Comment: This is a similar question to yours but unfortunately the answer is the URL you posted above: http://devforum.skype.com/t5/SkypeKit-API/Message-XML/m-p/20022/highlight/true#M2037

Comment: Yeah, that's where I found it :)

Comment: Doesn't the cited Skype documentation page lists the supported tags in the paragraphs following your quotation?
`<ss>`, `<flag>`, `<a>`, `<alertmatch>`, `<b>` and `<i>`

Comment: It says "Skype for Windows supports displaying many XML tags, but only a sub-set is regularly used and should be supported by the UI for a good experience. These are the ones described here." I read "These" as the "sub-set" and not the "many XML tags".

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Skype Developoer site:

http://developer.skype.com/skypekit/reference/dotnet/html/class_skype_kit_1_1_skt_message.html

Detailed Description -> "To strip the XML"

Comment: But that's the page I referenced in my question.

As I answered @obecker up in the question comments: It says "Skype for Windows supports displaying many XML tags, but only a sub-set is regularly used and should be supported by the UI for a good experience. These are the ones described here."

I read "These" as the "sub-set" and not the "many XML tags".

Comment: Ironic that this answer got the bounty when I down-voted it and it didn't answer the question :)